# Missing methods when upgrading to SDWebImage 5

Tags: ios, swift, sdwebimage

I'm upgrading a swift project from SDWebImage 3.7.5 to 5.12.3 and I have problems with a few methods which are not working anymore:

1. `SDWebImageManager.shared.cachedImageExists(for:)`
2. `SDWebImageManager.shared.imageCache.defaultCachePath(forKey:)`

Note: the SDWebImage migrating guides are not helpful in my situation because they may state which methods have disappeared but without specifying alternatives.

Comment: You need to check the whole Changelog, and look for `SDWebImageManager`: https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md
Then, we see that sync methoods seems to be removed, and you need to use async one? In 4.0: Removed the synchronous methods diskImageExistsForURL: and cachedImageExistsForURL: from SDWebImageManager Etc...

Comment: @Larme Thanks, but the changelog is not useful as well. It doesn't provide any alternatives (sync or async) to the removed methods.

Comment: There is `SDImageCache.shared` that could be used?

Comment: @Larme Yes indeed, but I don't know which method to use for cachedImageExists(for:) and defaultCachePath(forKey:). For reference: https://sdwebimage.github.io/SDWebImage/Classes/SDImageCache.html

Comment: `diskImageDataExistsWithKey` can be interesting, no? `defaultDiskCacheDirectory` too? `cachePathForKey`?

Comment: @Larme diskImageDataExistsWithKey is definitely interesting. The question is: was cachedImageExistsFor also checking for images in memory cache?

Comment: @Larme cachePathForKey sounds good too. I'm just wondering what was the meaning of "default" previously.

Comment: https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage/blob/3.7.5/SDWebImage/SDWebImageManager.m#L63 It was checking the ram and then the disk it seems so. I guess it might needs more digging into the lib...